# python package installation with pip

Tags: python, pip

I try to install pypcap in my windows 7

command : pip install pypcap

output:

Collecting pypcap

Using cached pypcap-1.1.1.tar.gz

```
pcap.h not found
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
pcap.h not found
```

I have put "pcap.h" on system path. where should i put the pcap.h so that pip can see it?
Thank

ps. show me how to get rid of extra space (new line) on this post